# Wordpress: How to embed a widget on a separate website?

Tags: widgets

A client requested that we make a copy of their WordPress widgets onto a separate, non-WP site.

Is there an easy way to "plug in" the widget? I imagine I would have to somehow source to something within the Wordpress backend.

Comment: You'll need to scrape it...or possibly iframe it. There's no other way to ensure it'll be able to dynamically update. Unless you're able to query the database from the other site...Lots of possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggested solution, it requires that you use [Widget Logic](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/) or [Dynamic Widgets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamics-sidebars/).

1. Add the code below to your theme or custom plugin
2. Insall one of the plugins I mentioned
3. Create the page(s) or post(s) that we'll use for the `iframe` `src` attribute on the non-WordPress site (give it a descriptive title, developers tend to forget a lot).
4. Add the widget you want to the sidebar "My Iframe" (if you didn't change that name)
5. Limit the widget to the page you created earlier, if you are using Sidebar Logic you'll then use the condition `is_single(N);` where N is the page or post ID.
6. Now you can add the iframe to the non-WordPress website, code below

---

Here's the code for 1st step:

```
/**
  * Verify dependencies 
  * 
  * In this example, we check for plugins in this order:
  * - Widgets Logic
  * - Dynamic Widgets
  */
define(
    'WPSE_168484_ERROR'
    , __( 'Please install and activate <strong>Widgets Logic</strong> or <strong>Dynamic Widgets</strong> and use one of them to show only one widget per page, you can still use many iframes in the non-WordPress website.' )
);

function_exists( 'widget_logic_options_control' )
|| defined( 'DW_VERSION')
|| die( WPSE_168484_ERROR );

// Declare sidebar
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'My Iframe', 'my_textdomain' ),
    'id' => 'my_iframe',
) );

// Show sidebar as HTML
add_action( 'init', 'my_iframe_widget' );
function my_iframe_widget() {
    if( is_active_sidebar( 'my_iframe' ) ) {

        // Get widget HTML
        ob_start();
        dynamic_sidebar( 'my_iframe' );
        $widget_html = ob_get_clean();

        // Remove wrapping <li>
        $widget_html = preg_replace( '/^<li.+>/', '', $widget_html );
        $widget_html = preg_replace( '/<\/li>$/m', '', $widget_html );

        // Make Valid HTML5 
        $widget_html = "<!doctype html><meta charset=utf-8>$widget_html";

        // Output and exit
        die( $widget_html );
    }
}
```

---

Here's the code for the 6th step:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/index.php?p=N" />
```

Replace http://example.com/ with your URL and N with the page or post ID.